# JQuery not initialized in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps, resize

I am trying to use JQuery in AngularJS.

In the Angular API it is said

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
    <title>INDEX</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<section>
    <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2659.8246953659373!2d16.39510611537435!3d48.190729055436904!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476d075e036ac393%3A0xa397f7b3829b7b3a!2sRennweg+89B%2C+1030+Wien!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sat!4v1477220288357" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> <!-- Jquery Code -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this in my Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function setWidth() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.map').css('width', windowWidth);
    };

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setWidth();
        console.log("Resize");
    });

});
```

I just want to set the width of the google map with Jquery depending on the WindowWidth, also on resizing.
Funny fact is that Jquery is not initialized but if i resize my window it suddenly works. 
After a reload it is gone.

Do I understand something wrong here?
Why is Jquery only initialized at triggering the resize function?

Comment: What do you mean by initialized? Jquery code is only called when you resize your window, are there any errors in your code?

Comment: I mean jquery loaded into the document, no there are no errors, unfortunately. @DZDomi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Error in your code the reason why the Frame is not full width is because you never get a resize event on loading: [working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ASPJcEgZHuw05pdulTch?p=preview)

But I would strongly suggest to load jQuery as top dependency to be sure that your `angular.element()` has the same functionality as `$()`
**index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> <!-- Jquery Code -->
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function setWidth() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.map').css('width', windowWidth);
    };
    //call it on load 
    setWidth();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setWidth();
        console.log("Resize");
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot to call the function on load... so yes it works but if buildung my project back with ng-view for routing i have the same issue. I just made a plunkr to show my problem. Again if i resize the window jquery function is triggered [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xN2xP1VlwGNJBcMTWgyK?p=preview)  @Bhuneshwer

Comment: yeah there is no onload event for route html. but im wondering if you wanna set the width of the iframe only to window width, why aren't you set it via CSS to width:100% ? [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h8Jw76QIhaXsrMqc5BqP?p=preview)

Comment: Alternatively if you _really_ want to do it with javascript do it this way: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8vq2SbTdtcdCFewF1OD?p=preview) (the angular way). Happy X-mas.

Comment: Yeah i know i could set the width to 100%, but i just want to do it with jquery in case i need jquery for something. I think it is clear for me know, prevent using jquery where it is not really needed and in case i would like to use it rewrite it with angular. Thanks a lot for the fast answers! Happy X-mas :)

Comment: It's not a bad thing to include JQuery in angular projects, but when you start with angular it's the best way to just work with jqlite (eg angular.element) to prevent unforseen circumstances. I learned it the hard way because we mixed our first angular project with JQuery and spend a lot of time to Debugg it on our own costs. I learned a lot, but it costs a lot of money.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

Move this line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

on top of

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

So your sequence should be

```
 <!-- First JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- AngularJS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```